# Project Specific Fields from a Foreign Collection $lookup result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, aggregation-framework

I'm writing aggregation to get foreign collection data with local collection.

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([
                    {
                        $match: {
                            status: "UNASSIGNED",
                            serviceLocationId: "83177"
                        }
                    }, {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: "servicelocations",
                            localField: "serviceLocationId",
                            foreignField: "serviceLocationId",
                            as: "locations"
                        }
                    }, {
                        $unwind: "$locations"
                    }])
```

I'm getting:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d32b5c360198e441b67545"),
    "accountId" : 1.0,
    "orderId" : "AQ137O1701240",
    "serviceLocationId" : "83177",
    "orderDate" : "2017-09-18T18:29:00.000Z",
    "description" : "AQ137O1701240",
    "serviceType" : "Delivery",
    "orderSource" : "Import",
    "takenBy" : "KARIM",
    "plannedDeliveryDate" : ISODate("2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "plannedDeliveryTime" : "",
    "actualDeliveryDate" : "",
    "actualDeliveryTime" : "",
    "deliveredBy" : "",
    "size1" : 25.0,
    "size2" : 464.0,
    "size3" : 46.0,
    "jobPriority" : 1.0,
    "cancelReason" : "",
    "cancelDate" : "",
    "cancelBy" : "",
    "reasonCode" : "",
    "reasonText" : "",
    "status" : "UNASSIGNED",
    "lineItems" : [ 
        {
            "ItemId" : "MMGW001",
            "size1" : 25.0,
            "size2" : 464.38,
            "size3" : 46.875
        }
    ],
    "locations" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ce18e172dbf6926093e189"),
        "accountId" : 1.0,
        "serviceLocationId" : "83177",
        "regionId" : "1",
        "zoneId" : "DXBZONE1",
        "description" : "EXPRESS BLUE MART SUPERMARKET",
        "locationPriority" : 1.0,
        "accountTypeId" : 1.0,
        "locationType" : "SERVICELOCATION",
        "location" : {
            "makani" : "",
            "lng" : 55.179042,
            "lat" : 25.098741
        },
        "deliveryDays" : "MTWRFSU",
        "serviceTimeTypeId" : "1",
        "timeWindow" : {
            "timeWindowTypeId" : "1"
        },
        "address1" : "",
        "address2" : "",
        "phone" : "",
        "city" : "",
        "county" : "",
        "state" : "",
        "country" : "",
        "zipcode" : "",
        "imageUrl" : "",
        "contact" : {
            "name" : "",
            "email" : ""
        },
        "status" : "ACTIVE",
        "createdBy" : "",
        "updatedBy" : "",
        "updateDate" : ""
    }
}
```

but i need:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d32b5c360198e441b67545"),
    "accountId" : 1.0,
    "orderId" : "AQ137O1701240",
    "serviceLocationId" : "83177",
    "orderDate" : "2017-09-18T18:29:00.000Z",
    "description" : "AQ137O1701240",
    "serviceType" : "Delivery",
    "orderSource" : "Import",
    "takenBy" : "KARIM",
    "plannedDeliveryDate" : ISODate("2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "plannedDeliveryTime" : "",
    "actualDeliveryDate" : "",
    "actualDeliveryTime" : "",
    "deliveredBy" : "",
    "size1" : 25.0,
    "size2" : 464.0,
    "size3" : 46.0,
    "jobPriority" : 1.0,
    "cancelReason" : "",
    "cancelDate" : "",
    "cancelBy" : "",
    "reasonCode" : "",
    "reasonText" : "",
    "status" : "UNASSIGNED",
    "lineItems" : [ 
        {
            "ItemId" : "MMGW001",
            "size1" : 25.0,
            "size2" : 464.38,
            "size3" : 46.875
        }
    ],
    "locations" : {
            "lng" : 55.179042,
            "lat" : 25.098741
        }
}
```

Comment: What about projection?

Comment: if i writing projection i'm get foreign data only., i'm not get local collection data. @john

Comment: You have to instruct the projection what to include. If you don't get local collection data, that's because you're not including it in your projection.

Comment: ``[{$match:{status:"UNASSIGNED",serviceLocationId:"83177"}},{$lookup:{from:"servicelocations",localField:"serviceLocationId",foreignField:"serviceLocationId",as:"locations"}},{$unwind:"$locations"},{$project:{locations:1}}]`` this way i'm using projection. @john

Comment: ``{"_id":ObjectId("59d32b5c360198e441b67545"),"locations":{"_id":ObjectId("59ce18e172dbf6926093e189"),"accountId":1.0,"serviceLocationId":"83177","regionId":"1","zoneId":"DXBZONE1","description":"EXPRESS BLUE MART SUPERMARKET","locationPriority":1.0,"accountTypeId":1.0,"locationType":"SERVICELOCATION","location":{"makani":"","lng":55.179042,"lat":25.098741},"deliveryDays":"MTWRFSU","serviceTimeTypeId":"1","timeWindow":{"timeWindowTypeId":"1"},"country":"","zipcode":"","imageUrl":"","contact":{"name":"","email":""}}}`` i'm getting but i need above result @john

Comment: @john That is "one" approach. But there are others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## MongoDB less than 3.4.4

Basically, use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) as a final stage and select ALL the specific fields you want. Unfortunately [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) is out because it will actually "merge" the sub-keys with the existing ones. So the seemingly simple:

```
{ "$addFields": {
  "locations": {
    "lng": "$locations.location.lng",
    "lat": "$locations.location.lat"    
  }
}}
```

Just gives you all the existing content under `"locations"` as well as the those newly defined keys. Unless of course you don't [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) directly after the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), which you can do if this would not cause the [BSON limit to be exceeded](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#lookup-unwind-coalescence). ( this is called `$lookup`  + `$unwind` coalescence )

Then we can use [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), because we can simply "re-map" the array:

```
   { "$addFields": {
     "locations": {
       "$map": {
         "input": "$locations",
         "as": "l",
         "in": {
           "lng": "$$l.location.lng",
           "lat": "$$l.location.lat"
         }
       } 
     }  
   }},
   { "$unwind": "$locations" }
```

And then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) if you still need to after that re-mapping.

So with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) it is:

```
  { "$project": {
    "accountId" : 1,
    "orderId" : 1,
    "serviceLocationId" : 1,
    "orderDate" : 1,
    "description" : 1,
    "serviceType" : 1,
    "orderSource" : 1,
    "takenBy" : 1,
    "plannedDeliveryDate" : 1,
    "plannedDeliveryTime" : 1,
    "actualDeliveryDate" : 1,
    "actualDeliveryTime" : 1,
    "deliveredBy" : 1,
    "size1" : 1,
    "size2" : 1,
    "size3" : 1,
    "jobPriority" : 1,
    "cancelReason" : 1,
    "cancelDate" : 1,
    "cancelBy" : 1,
    "reasonCode" : 1,
    "reasonText" : 1,
    "status" : 1,
    "lineItems" : 1,
    "locations" : {
      "lng": "$locations.location.lng",
      "lat": "$locations.location.lat"    
    }
  }}
```

Simple but long winded.

## MongoDB 3.4.4 Or greater

If you have MongoDB 3.4.4 or greater with [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/), then you can be a bit more fancy about it:

```
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": {  
      "$arrayToObject": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          { "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this.k", "locations" ] }
          }},
          { "$objectToArray": {
            "locations": {
              "lng": "$locations.location.lng",
              "lat": "$locations.location.lat"    
            }
          }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
```

Which basically takes all the fields presently in the whole document from `$$ROOT`, turns it into an array format. We then [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) the `"location"` field by the "key name" and [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) it with the new `"location"` key and sub-keys again transformed into an array.

Finally of course [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) takes that and transforms back into an object which is supplied to `newRoot` of [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) as the final output.

---

So using either of those except [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) after [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) of course gives you the correct result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d32b5c360198e441b67545"),
    "accountId" : 1.0,
    "orderId" : "AQ137O1701240",
    "serviceLocationId" : "83177",
    "orderDate" : "2017-09-18T18:29:00.000Z",
    "description" : "AQ137O1701240",
    "serviceType" : "Delivery",
    "orderSource" : "Import",
    "takenBy" : "KARIM",
    "plannedDeliveryDate" : ISODate("2017-10-09T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "plannedDeliveryTime" : "",
    "actualDeliveryDate" : "",
    "actualDeliveryTime" : "",
    "deliveredBy" : "",
    "size1" : 25.0,
    "size2" : 464.0,
    "size3" : 46.0,
    "jobPriority" : 1.0,
    "cancelReason" : "",
    "cancelDate" : "",
    "cancelBy" : "",
    "reasonCode" : "",
    "reasonText" : "",
    "status" : "UNASSIGNED",
    "lineItems" : [ 
        {
            "ItemId" : "MMGW001",
            "size1" : 25.0,
            "size2" : 464.38,
            "size3" : 46.875
        }
    ],
    "locations" : {
        "lng" : 55.179042,
        "lat" : 25.098741
    }
}
```

---

## MongoDB 3.6 and greater

As a bit of a preview, [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) gets a more expressive overhaul with MongoDB 3.6. So you can actually specifically state the fields to return that way:

```
{ "$lookup": {
  "from": "servicelocations",
  "let": { "serviceLocationId": "$serviceLocationId" },
  "pipeline": [
    { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "serviceLocationId", "$$serviceLocationId" ] } }},
    { "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "lng": "$location.lng",
      "lat": "$location.lat"
    }}
  ],
  "as": "locations"
}}
```

Little bit more handy when that is actually released. This actually uses [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/expr/) instead of the `localField` and `foreignField` to define the "join" condition in a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage of the sub-pipeline. Then you can simply [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the fields to return, which then go into the array targeted by [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup).

Going forward, that's the general approach you would want to take as it limits what actually gets returned.